# ios simulator 6.0 displaying view issue

Tags: xcode, ios6, ios-simulator

First time trying to develop app for iOS 6. I am having issue with displaying app in 4-inch display size in iOS Simulator 6.0, it displays like app for 3.5-inch display with black areas in top and bottom. I switched settings to:

- in Xcode: Deployment target - 6.0
- scheme - iPhone 6.0 Simulator
- in Simulator device is iPhone retina 4-inch, version 6.0
- in Interface Builder it is a 4-inch Views.

I am also tried to clean the project and to reset the settings of a Simulator. So is it a bug of a simulator or there is another option to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have a 568@2x splash screen?

Comment: Hm.. I deleted it by imprudence when started a project. Now added it to project again and the problem solves! Can you explain what the mission of this splashscreen in this case?

Comment: The SDK uses the presence of this splashscreen as a flag telling "This app is compatible with the new 4” Retina screen of the iPhone5".

Answer (score 1):

Adding Defaut-568h@2x.png will fix this issue.

Sometimes you may also come across the same issue when you are developing an application that supports in lower versions too.

In this case, setting your view frames to [[UIScreen mainScreen] Bounds] will fix the issue.